# Pandas resample monthly data into custom frequency (seasonal) data

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-resample

### Background

I have a monthly dataset and want to resample it to seasonal by adding monthly data.

```
Seasonal refers to:
(Dec,Jan,Feb), (Mar,Apr,May),(June,July,Aug,Sep),(Oct,Nov)
```

### The Data

```
dti = pd.date_range("2015-12-31", periods=11, freq="M")
df = pd.DataFrame({'time':dti,
                  'data':np.random.rand(len(dti))})

Output:
        time    data
0   2015-12-31  0.466245
1   2016-01-31  0.959309
2   2016-02-29  0.445139
3   2016-03-31  0.575556
4   2016-04-30  0.303020
5   2016-05-31  0.591516
6   2016-06-30  0.001410
7   2016-07-31  0.338360
8   2016-08-31  0.540705
9   2016-09-30  0.115278
10  2016-10-31  0.950359
```

### Code

So, I was able to do resample for other seasons except Dec, Jan, Feb (DJF). Here is what I have done for other seasons:

```
MAM = df.loc[df['time'].dt.month.between(3,5)].resample('Y',on='time').sum()
```

Since, for DJF I couldn't use `between`, I used a conditional statement.

```
mask = (df['time'].dt.month>11) | (df['time'].dt.month<=2)
DJF = df.loc[mask].resample('3M',origin='start',on='time').sum()
```

### The Issue

This resampling leaves my first data '2015-12-31' as it is and starts from the '2016' even though I used `origin = 'start'`.
So, my questions are basically :

1. How do I solve my resampling  issue ?
2. I feel like there must be a more straight forward and easier way to do this rather than conditional statements. Also, Is there anything similar to using `df['time'].month.between` but for index. I tried using `df.index.month.between` but between doesn't work for int64 datetime object. I found repetitively using `df.set_index` and `df.reset_index` quite tiresome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try mapping each month value to a season value then [`groupby resample`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.resample.html#pandas-core-groupby-dataframegroupby-resample) on each season:

```
df['season'] = df['time'].dt.month.map({
    12: 0, 1: 0, 2: 0,
    3: 1, 4: 1, 5: 1,
    6: 2, 7: 2, 8: 2, 9: 2,
    10: 3, 11: 3
})

df = df.groupby('season').resample('Y', on='time')['data'].sum().reset_index()
```

`df`:

```
   season       time      data
0       0 2015-12-31  0.221993
1       0 2016-12-31  1.077451
2       1 2016-12-31  2.018766
3       2 2016-12-31  1.768848
4       3 2016-12-31  0.080741
```

To consider the previous December as part of the next year add [`MonthBegin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.tseries.offsets.MonthBegin.html#pandas-tseries-offsets-monthbegin) from `pandas.tseries.offsets` to offset December 2015 to January 2016, then adjust all Season values forward one month:

```
df['time'] = df['time'] + MonthBegin(1)
df['season'] = df['time'].dt.month.map({
    1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 0,
    4: 1, 5: 1, 6: 1,
    7: 2, 8: 2, 9: 2, 10: 2,
    11: 3, 12: 3
})

df = df.groupby('season').resample('Y', on='time')['data'].sum().reset_index()
```

`df`:

```
   season       time      data
0       0 2016-12-31  1.299445
1       1 2016-12-31  2.018766
2       2 2016-12-31  1.768848
3       3 2016-12-31  0.080741
```

---

Sample Data Used:

```
np.random.seed(5)
dti = pd.date_range("2015-12-31", periods=11, freq="M")
df = pd.DataFrame({'time': dti,
                   'data': np.random.rand(len(dti))})
```

`df`:

```
         time      data
0  2015-12-31  0.221993
1  2016-01-31  0.870732
2  2016-02-29  0.206719
3  2016-03-31  0.918611
4  2016-04-30  0.488411
5  2016-05-31  0.611744
6  2016-06-30  0.765908
7  2016-07-31  0.518418
8  2016-08-31  0.296801
9  2016-09-30  0.187721
10 2016-10-31  0.080741
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ! Great to know about mapping functionalities. However, I am getting `NameError: name 'MonthBegin' is not defined` when trying to offset.

Comment: Nvm, Using `pd.offsets.MonthBegin()` resoved the issue.

Comment: You can also import `MonthBegin` to use it like I did with `from pandas.tseries.offsets import MonthBegin`